# How to Add and delete elements to array with one unique function (handleClick) in react js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I hope you can help me, I am wanting to add and remove elements from an array with the same function in this case with the handleClick function.
I have a list in this case of letters when I click on a letter it is added to the array (this functionality is already there). Now, when clicking on the same letter again that is already in the array, it must be removed with the same handle click.
I have already tried everything and am stuck, hope with your help I can solve this. Thanks!

Here is the code that I have, I also leave the link to code sandbox so that you can see it more clearly
https://codesandbox.io/s/unique-function-to-add-and-delete-cibdy?file=/src/App.js:0-797

```html
   
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [arrayUnique, setArrayUnique] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
    setList([...list, e.target.innerText]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const filterCounters = () => {
      let uniqueCounters = Array.from(new Set(list));
      setArrayUnique(uniqueCounters);
    };
    filterCounters();
  }, [list]);

  console.log("-list-", list);
  console.log("arrayUnique", arrayUnique);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {x.map((item, i) => (
        <li onClick={handleClick} key={i}>
          {item}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basicly what u need is to check if your list has the innerText or not so:

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
  if(list.includes(e.target.innerText)) {
    setList([
      ...list.filter(ch => ch !== e.target.innerText)
    ])
  }
  else {
    setList([...list, e.target.innerText]);
  }
};
```